# gnuplot: silent error reading (non-standard form of) scientific format numbers

Tags: gnuplot, precision, scatter-plot, linechart, scientific-notation

**EDIT**: Since I found the problem, I've corrected the question.

I have a program that generates data for GNUPlot to plot. Everything works fine, except for one thing: the data program generates is in double-float format and printable representation of this data is, for example `1.2d0` or `6.3d-5` (standard representation for Common Lisp).

GNUPlot, however, expects numbers in the form `1.2` or `6.3e-5`. Perhaps, GNUPlot might be giving a warning when reading the data, but since all the data is piped through, it doesn't show up. So, what is happening: GNUPlot happily reads the number until it encounters `dXXX` suffix and silently drops it. This leads to something rather unexpected. For example, to plot `y=sin(x)` from the program, the data lines near `x=pi` look as follows

```
2.9670597283903604d0 0.17364817766693028d0
3.141592653589793d0 1.2246467991473532d-16
3.3161255787892263d0 -0.17364817766693047d0
```

So, for `x=3.14159...` GNUPlot reads `y=1.2246...` instead of `y=1.2246...e-16`. And the plot has an unexpected spike (see below).

[image: sin(x) with spike]

Solution in my case: convert data to single-float or change the printable representation of double-floats.

Comment: I've never seen such an error, please show the script and the raw data row in you file eyou are using.

Comment: I think I found where the error was. The data row for that point looks like this `3.141592653589793d0 1.2246467991473532d-16`  -- so, double-float numbers are formatted with `dXXX` at the end. I feel that GNUPlot cannot read numbers in this form and needs `eXXX`. So if the last number was written `1.2246...e-16` there wouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Christoph The error is indeed as mentioned above. I have corrected the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That format is also used by Fortran. Gnuplot offers an option to enable checking for `D` and `Q` constants in the data file:

```
set datafile fortran

plot '-' using 1:2 w lp
2.9670597283903604d0 0.17364817766693028d0
3.141592653589793d0 1.2246467991473532d-16
3.3161255787892263d0 -0.17364817766693047d0
e
```

According to the docs that option is not enabled by default because it slows down the input process.